# ElasticSearch: Query to find max of count of objects based on field value

Tags: elasticsearch

For the example document below in the index, I want to find max of count of actions based on component name across all documents in the index. Could you please help to find a way for this.

**Expected result assuming only one document present in the Index:**

```
comp1 -> action1 -> max 2 times
comp1 -> action2 -> max 1 time
comp2 -> action2 -> max 1 time
comp2 -> action3 -> max 1 time
```

**Sample Document:**

```
{
  "id": "AC103902:A13A_AC140008:01BB_5FA2E8FA_1C08:0007",
  "tokens": [
    {
      "name": "comp1",
      "items": [
        {
          "action": "action1",
          "attr": "value"
        },
        {
          "action": "action1",
          "attr": "value"
        },
        {
          "action": "action2",
          "attr": "value"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "comp2",
      "items": [
        {
          "action": "action2",
          "attr": "value"
        },
        {
          "action": "action3",
          "attr": "value"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**ElasticSearch Version:** 7.9
I can loop through each document and calculate this at client side but I am curious to know if there is already an ES query which can help to get this kid of summary from the documents in the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to define both the `tokens` array and the `tokens.items` array as [`nested`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) in order to get the correct stats.

Then, assuming your mapping looks something along the lines of

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "tokens": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "items": {
            "type": "nested"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

the following query can be executed:

```
GET index_name/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "by_token_name": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "tokens"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "token_name": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "tokens.name.keyword"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "by_max_actions": {
              "nested": {
                "path": "tokens.items"
              },
              "aggs": {
                "max_actions": {
                  "terms": {
                    "field": "tokens.items.action.keyword"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

yielding these buckets:

```
[
  {
    "key" : "comp1",              <--
    "doc_count" : 1,
    "by_max_actions" : {
      "doc_count" : 3,
      "max_actions" : {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
        "buckets" : [
          {
            "key" : "action1",    <--
            "doc_count" : 2
          },
          {
            "key" : "action2",    <--
            "doc_count" : 1
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "key" : "comp2",              <--
    "doc_count" : 1,
    "by_max_actions" : {
      "doc_count" : 2,
      "max_actions" : {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
        "buckets" : [
          {
            "key" : "action2",    <--
            "doc_count" : 1
          },
          {
            "key" : "action3",    <--
            "doc_count" : 1
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]
```

which can be easily post-processed at client side.